# Populate TableView from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to populate a tableview with a list of strings stored in parse.com.
 I did this 3 steps but is not returning anything, is not the same as with a normal array? Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self PFQueryNotes]; 
}

 //PFQuery Notes
- (void)PFQueryNotes {
    // Using PFQuery
    PFQuery *notesquery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Notes"];
    self.notesArray = [notesquery findObjects];
}    

//Returns the number of cells to display in the tableview
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.notesArray count];
}

//Fills the cells with the array values
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: After the query completes, you should call [self.tableView reloadData];  Also make sure that the tableview datasource points to this view controller.  Once its working, you'll want to change that synchronous form of find to findObjectsInBackground...

Comment: Oops.  Also, its not right to assign a label's text to a PFObject.  Do something like `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"someStringAttribute"]`

Comment: Use a `PFQueryTableViewController`. It does the basic query managing for you.

Comment: @Schemetrical but can I use it with a tableview inside a normal view controller?

Comment: Oh, that's what you need. Unfortunately you must manage it manually. By the way, findObjects is synchronous, it will block the main thread.

Comment: I think you're off to a good start with a regular UIViewController.  PFQueryTableVC (imo) provides a small head-start but becomes a liability as soon as you want something other than a simple table.